# Parse check if email exists query

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to get a query of all the emails from Parse and check if it is the same as one that a user inputs.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:emailerL];
NSArray *emailers = [query findObjects];
if ([emailers containsObject:emailerL]) {
    [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:emailerL];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please try again" message:@"Email does not exist" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Gotcha" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

I don't know why the if statement isn't working. (emailers is an array and emailerL is a string).

I guess I just need help with comparing a string to data in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for at least one record that matches a query, use `getFirstObject` instead, it will return `nil` if it doesn't find a match and will be a lot quicker.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:emailerL];

if ([query getFirstObject]) {
    [PFUser requestParrwordResetForEmailInBackground:emailerL];
    // ... etc ...
```

Of course, you should really be using the "in background" version, but this is your first step to try.

Answer (score 1):

A better way that doesn't involve downloading the actually object, but just checking:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:emailerL];
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
  if(number > 0) {
     ... it exists!
 }
}];
```

Of course, there is the single threaded approach, though as Timothy mentions, you should really be using background.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:emailerL];
if([query countObjects] > 0) {
   ... it exists!
}
```